# lying down and then sit up/down?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

If your child is lying down and you want them to get in the sitting position, how do you ask them to in an informal/everyday language?
If you could provide more than one way, it would be appreciated.

Comment: learner, the usual wording is *lying down*. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/lying?q=lying and http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/lie-down_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a "Sit up" will do. See simple things in simple ways.

Comment: since you asked for more than one way, I would add the following: "sit up, I said", "sit up, dang it", "when are you going to sit up?", and, finally, "if you don't sit up I will make sure you *really* don't want to sit up"